# Submit a form to a Rails route with a dynamic segment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have a route that looks like

```
match 'solar_systems/:planet_num/:moon_num' => 'solar_system#moon', :as => :moon
```

I'd like to have a form with a select box for planet number and moon number and have it submit to this route. However I cannot use `moon_path` because it will have an error if the dynamic parameters are not included in it like this `moon_path(4, 1)`. Is what I want even possible? If so, what do I give to the form tag for the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't **have** to use the routing helper methods, and here you can't since at the time of rendering your form you do not know the required parameters. You do, however, know the controller and action, which is really all that's needed for the destination URL. So this should work:

```
= form_tag('/solar_systems/moon') do
  = select_tag(:planet_num, ...
  = select_tag(:moon_num, ...
```

This should render the form tag. To process the request, you will also have to add another route so the right controller action is called:

```
match 'solar_systems#moon' => 'solar_system#moon', :via => :post
```

Or, if it makes more sense in the context of your application, you could modify your existing route to make the parameters optional:

```
match 'solar_systems(/:planet_num(/:moon_num')) => 'solar_system#moon', :as => :moon
```

See [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) for more details on non-resourceful routes.

Comment: This doesn't work because I don't have any other routes that match this so I get the error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/solar_systems/moon"):`

Comment: Please see my additions concerning routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this params on controller you need to specified what params is each one, btw in you helper you need to do something like this

```
moon_path(planet_moon: 4, moon_num: 1)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Right, that's how I'd use it link it to specific values. I'm trying to use it in a form where the values are not yet known. Though I'm starting to believe that what I'm trying to do exactly is not possible in Rails w/o some JS on the page.